# Handling function return value of pointers passed as argument in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

My question involves methods like memset and strcat that return pointers that were passed as arguments. For instance:

Case 1:

```
const char *src = /*assign space*/;
char *dst = /*assign space*/;
dst = strcat(dst, src);
```

Case 2:

```
const char *src = /*assign space*/;
char *dst = /*assign space*/;
strcat(dst, src);
```

Can case 2 be considered unsafe peradventure the called function changes the memory pointed to. Should the explicit reassignment of case 1 be used always?

If to use case 2, can a variant:

```
char * const dst = /*assign space*/;
```

be used to ensure that the pointer remains the same after the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Normally*" you don't use explicit assignment, this is enough

```
strcat(dst, src);
```

the returned pointer and the passed pointer both contain the same address, i.e. the address of the memory you previously allocated.

- It's safe to do any of the two, assigning a pointer to itself doesn't make much sense though.

This was extracted from the [linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html) manual for `strcat()`

> ```
>   A simple implementation of strncat() might be:
>
>        char*
>        strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
>        {
>            size_t dest_len = strlen(dest);
>            size_t i;
>
>           for (i = 0 ; i < n && src[i] != '\0' ; i++)
>                dest[dest_len + i] = src[i];
>            dest[dest_len + i] = '\0';
>
>           return dest;
>        }
> ```

as you can see, `dest` is not changed so the returned pointer and the passed pointer point to the same address.

And this

```
char * const dst = /*assign space*/;
```

will not let you do

```
dst = strcat(dst, src);
```

so, it forces you to use the first method anyway.

Comment: Thanks @iharob. Are there any functions existing in the standard library that could reallocate the memory?

Comment: Thanks @tux3. Are there any functions existing in the standard library that could reallocate the memory?

Comment: Yes `realloc()` it takes care of copying the old data to the new memory if necessary and it frees the memory if necessary too.

Answer (score 3):

Both of your cases would be just as safe, but the extra assignment in the first one is not needed.

`strcat` doesn't reallocate anything, and doesn't "changes the memory pointed to", so there's no need to take the return value here. The pointer is *guaranteed* to remain the same after the call.

Comment: No I'm not modifying a const char*. I'm modifying the location pointed to by dst. src is not modified, only copied from.

Comment: @user3814660 The purpose of `strcat` is to add something at the end of `dst`. This implies that `dst` must be large enough and not `const`, because it'll be modified. If you really want to use a `char*` you could write something like `char* dst = "Test\0Empty space"`, but it's not very clean.

Comment: yes true. But trying to draw attention to "You're trying to modify a const char* with strcat, which is undefined behavior." The char from src is appended to dst, as you stated. But your quoted statement, I don't see how this is true from the code snippet.

Comment: @user3814660 That was unclear. `strcat` modifies the string pointed to by your `const char*`, I'll fix that, thanks :)

Comment: :) I guess you mean "`strcat` modifies the string pointed to by your `char *`"

Comment: @user3814660 `strcat` reads from `src` and writes to `dst`. So it modifies the string pointed to by `dst`, the `const char*`.  This time it's not a mistake :)

Comment: Oh the mistake is your reading the post then. There's no `const char * dst` declaration in the post. Am i missing something? @tux3

Comment: @user3814660 There is in your variant of case 2, but I must have misread it for the first two

Comment: @user3814660 Oh, or maybe that was a different dst. Right, I'll just remove that part. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`dst` will not change. `dst` **must** be large enough to contain the concatenated string.

So no memory is allocated by `strcat()`.